# Why won't Azure VM serve SSL?

Tags: ssl, azure-web-app-service, iis-7.5

My Azure VM (Win 2008 R2 Datacenter) runs IIS 7.5 and hosts a half-dozen Web sites. I obtained and installed a certificate to enable SSL on one site. I tested the  certificate with the downloaded SSL Diagnostics tool, and all appears great. The tool sent a sample SSL handshake with perfect results (diagnostic info along with the contents of the tiny test web page).

However, the web page is unobtainable using https://... from a browser on either the server or client. Localhost:443 or the server IP address:443 in a browser on the server also fails. No error messages are received, the browser just waits and waits.

What could it be?

If I use a browser on the server and input https://ip address without 443, I get this error in the browser: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. "Your connection is not private. Attackers might be trying to steal your information..." and it shows the info from the certificate, like the issuer etc. What's the deal?

Comment: What are the site bindings you use? https://<IP> works only indicates the site bindings accept such requests, but you do need to revise the bindings to accept https://<domain name> . You need to collect more information via a tool such as Binding Diagnostics https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. I needed to open port 443 in the Azure Portal, in my Network Security Group. Another question on StackOverflow steered me to that solution!

Comment: @OP, it's fine to self-answer your own question. This can be turned into an acceptable answer if you [edit] it to add a link to the other question that steered you to the solution.

Comment: Sorry I don't recall the other question.